# Voltage of capacitor in underdamped RLC circuit

Tags: voltage, capacitor, passive-networks

I have this circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fI54Cj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If the capacitor is precharged this circuit has an underdamped response and for VC1 = 10V the equation for current I(t)=1.05e^(-5t)sin(95t)A

How do find the equation for voltage across C1? Can I use this formula?
\$Vc1 = Vo+\frac{1}{C}*\int(I(t)dt)\$?

Comment: An underdamped oscillator will have an exponential decay term.

Comment: Yes sorry  I only wrote part of the expression now it is corrected.

Comment: btw - I don't think your value of 95 is correct. It should be \$\sqrt{10000-25} = 99.87...\$

Comment: @ErikR the neper frequeny is equal to 5.So the frequency of the underdamped oscillation is natural frequency-neper frequency = 100-5=95 rad/s.

Comment: I'd double check that... everything I've seen says \$\omega_d^2 = \omega_0^2 - \alpha^2\$ where \$\omega_d\$ is the damped frequency, \$\omega_0\$ is the natural frequency and \$\alpha\$ is the neper frequency.

Comment: Yes you are correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/125019/discussion-between-erikr-and-jun-seo-he).

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Now you can look up the exponential waveform for this initial condition that includes Q or ζ=1/2Q .
this is your homework.

This is how I started doing it in 1975. It still works.

Comment: Cant I solve it algebraically?

Comment: Jun the impedances are on the graph, yes you can solve that in time or frequency domain

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=rlc

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have the equation for \$I(t)\$, if you want to solve it algebraically I would start with this KVL equation:

$$
L\frac{d}{dt}I(t) + RI(t) + V_C(t) = 0
$$
or
$$
V_C(t) = - L\frac{d}{dt}I(t) - RI(t) 
$$

You'll get a combination of \$\sin\$ and \$\cos\$ terms, e.g.

$$
A\cos 95t + B\sin 95t
$$

You can transform that into the form \$C\sin(95t + \delta)\$ by solving:

$$
C = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}, \sin\delta = \frac{A}{C}, \cos\delta = \frac{B}{C}
$$

**Update:** If you follow through with this approach you should be able to derive this:

$$
    V_C(t) = -I_0\sqrt{\frac{L}{C}}e^{-\gamma t}\cos(\omega t - \delta)
$$
where \$\sin \delta = \frac{RC}{2\sqrt{LC}}\$ and the current is given by \$I(t) = I_0e^{-\gamma t}\sin \omega t \$. And don't forget about the approximation \$\sin \delta = \delta\$ for small values of \$\delta\$.